# How to scan directory with multi-thread

Tags: java, database, multithreading, file, directory

I have a directory scan program with single thread. When scanning a file, I have to read attribute information and insert it to database.

I have 2 questions. In order to improve the performance:

1. How to scan with multi-thread? (scan sd card of Android phone)
2. How to optimize the batch insert to DB?

Below is the code listing:

```
void scan() {
    File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard");
    fun(file);
}

void fun(File file) {
    if (!file.exists()) {
        return;
    }
    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
        // read attribute information and insert to db
        return;
    } else {
        File[] arr = file.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            fun(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ask one question at a time, that's how the questions are of most use to others. Especially when they're completely unrelated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can increase the performance using multithreads, while one is making disk I/O another one is doing network I/O, I will write a small example of this.

here is the example, better then read before sleep :) with the constructor of the class `ReadThenAll(5);` you create 5 threads to explore the folders and subfolders. have fun !!

```
package foo;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

public class ReadThenAll {

    // subfolders to explore
    private final Queue exploreList = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();

    private long counter = 0;

    public void count() {
        counter++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ReadThenAll me = new ReadThenAll(5);
        me.scan("/tmp");

    }

    int[] threads;

    public ReadThenAll(int numberOfThreads) {
        threads = new int[numberOfThreads];

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = -1;
        }
    }

    void scan(String fileName) {

        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // add the first one to the list
        File file = new File(fileName);
        exploreList.add(file);

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            FileExplorer explorer = new FileExplorer(i, this);
            Thread t = new Thread(explorer);
            t.start();
        }

        Thread waitToFinish = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                boolean working = true;
                while (working) {
                    working = false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
                        if (threads[i] == -1) {
                            working = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                System.out.println("total time (ms) : " + elapsed);

            }
        });

        waitToFinish.start();
    }

    public void done(int id, int counter) {
        threads[id] = counter;
    }

    class FileExplorer implements Runnable {

        public int counter = 0;
        public ReadThenAll owner;
        private int id;

        public FileExplorer(int id, ReadThenAll owner) {
            this.id = id;
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!owner.exploreList.isEmpty()) {

                // get the first from the list
                try {
                    File file = (File) owner.exploreList.remove();

                    if (file.exists()) {

                        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                            doThemagic(file);
                        } else {

                            // add the files to the queue
                            File[] arr = file.listFiles();
                            if (arr != null) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                    owner.exploreList.add(arr[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // silent kill :)
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            owner.done(id, counter);
            System.out.println("total of files : " + counter);
        }

        private void doThemagic(File file) {
            System.out.println(file.toString());
            counter++;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think using multithread is going to help here. Scanning directory is IO bounded. Even if you use multiple thread, they are all going to wait for the IO operation to finish in a working thread. So at anytime there is only one thread scanning.

It will help unless the IO operation on your directory can be parallelized, e.g. multiple disks..

Comment: @user2130265 you could have accepted it as the answer, which could increase my "reputation points" :)

Comment: actually, reading file attributes might be faster when using multiple threads because it's only querying the file system, not reading stuff all over the disk. but, the only way to prove it is to try it.

Comment: I just tried :) tested with the code that I add to my answer. just the reading with 5 threads were faster.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow below one of the design

```
1 - Create a queue in which supports multiple read  and single write.
2-  Get the number of cpu in the system in which you need to run the program because you can not run more threads simultaneously.

3- I/O is always blocking if you have 2 threads which are writing on Disk then they have to be serialized or you have multiple physical storage devices so you can access those.

4- The Queue you created in step 1 , you can write into the queue and simultaneously read.

5- Again database operation is blocking one that means your thread has to wait until it got the response from the db server rather than blocking the thread you can think of asynchronous  processing and callback mechanism.
```